# transform for loops into list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Just started learning list comprehension in Python and confusing a lot.

My code is:

```
    no_duplicates_list = []    
    for url in sorted_temp_list:
        found = False
        for index, url_for_comparing in enumerate(sorted_temp_list):
            if url in url_for_comparing and url != url_for_comparing:
                sorted_temp_list[index] = url
                found = True
        if found is True:
            no_duplicates_list.append(url)

    return no_duplicates_list
```

Already spent huge time with it but can't understand how to add boolean variable inside and variable assignment.

More details where I use it:
if a url is parent, all other urls with the the first url as the prefix should be removed.  Here is an example

1. aaaccc.com/a
2. aaaccc.com/a/b
3. aaaccc.com/a/b/c
4. aaaccc.com/a/c
5. aaaccc.com/a/d
6. aaaccc.com/a/e
7. aaaccc.com/b/bc
8. aaaccc.com/b/bc/a
9. aaaccc.com/b/bc/b

In the above list since url 1 is in the list, rows 2 through 6 will inherit that reputation. Similarly, due to row 7, rows 8 and 9 also not necessary as they will inherit reputation from 7.

Comment: List comprehension is not for cramming all and sundry (e.g assignment) in between a pair of square braces. You generally would not execute statements in a list comprehension.

Comment: To paraphrase Moses (in a somewhat more verbose way): all loops are not meant to be rewritten as list expressions, and one the best criterion is whether writing it as a list expression is harder than keeping it as a plain for loop.

Comment: so should I combine lambda expressions with it? I have just got a notice from others that for loops is not good idea. So Im looking for other solutions. Where do you think I should look for ideas?

Comment: Actually, if you add a `break` in your `for` loop, it could well be more efficient than a list comp. anyway. After `found = True` add a `break` and use `if found:` instead of `if found is True` and it's not bad code from what I can see.

Comment: Removing duplicates from lists can be done as `list(set(mylist))`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists) for details.

Comment: actually my task is a little bit harder than removing duplicates from list :)

Comment: if a url is parent, all other urls with the the first url as the prefix should be removed.  Here is an example
1. aaaccc.com/a
2. aaaccc.com/a/b
3. aaaccc.com/a/b/c
4. aaaccc.com/a/c
5. aaaccc.com/a/d
6. aaaccc.com/a/e
7. aaaccc.com/b/bc
8. aaaccc.com/b/bc/a
9. aaaccc.com/b/bc/b
In the above list since url 1 is in the list, rows 2 through 6 will inherit that reputation. Similarly, due to row 7, rows 8 and 9 do not need to be deployed as they will inherit reputation from 7. Sorry for formatting :(

Comment: updated the problem details for better understanding where I use it